# Warning: : No such file or directory in C

Tags: php

I'm working on mvc framework for a website and just want to delete old image from my image folder when i' m editing a post but get this errors:

> Warning: unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\Model View Controller2/public/images/2425.jpg): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Model View Controller2\app\Controller\Admin\ServicesController.php on line 72

This is my controller (when I'm editing the same image old one is deleted; its what i want for different image)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;
use Core\HTML\BootstrapForm;
use \App;
class ServicesController extends AppController{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->loadModel('Service');
    }

    public function index(){
        $services = $this->Service->all();
        $this->render('admin.services.index', compact('services'));
    }


    public function edit(){
        $errors = false;
        $this->loadModel('Service');
        if (!empty($_POST)) {

            if($_FILES['img']['size'] > 1500000){
                $errors = "<strong>Ce fichier est trop lourd !</strong>";
            }

            if(strrchr($_FILES['img']['name'], '.') !== '.jpg'){
                $errors = "<strong>L'extension de ce fichier n'est pas un .jpg !</strong>";
            }


            if($errors != true){

                $dir = '../public/images/';
                print_r($dir.$_FILES['img']['name']);
                unlink($dir.$_FILES['img']['name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $dir.$_FILES['img']['name']);
                $result = $this->Service->update($_GET['id'], array(
                    'titre' => $_POST['titre'],
                'contenu' => $_POST['contenu'],
                    'img' => $dir.$_FILES['img']['name']));
            }


        }
        $service = $this->Service->find($_GET['id']);

        $services = $this->Service->extract('id', 'titre', 'contenu', 'img');
        $form = new BootstrapForm($service);
        $this->render('admin.services.edit', compact('services', 'form', 'errors'));
    }

    public function delete(){
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $result = $this->Service->delete($_POST['id']);
            return $this->index();
        }
    }

}`
```

this is my view form edtit.php

```
<center><h1>Editer la page d'accueil Services</h1></center> 

    <?php if($errors): ?>
        <center class="alert alert-danger">
        <?= $errors; ?>
        </center>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form class="edit" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?= $form->input('titre', 'Titre'); ?>
        <?= $form->input('contenu', 'Message', array('type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => 8)); ?>
        <?= $form->input('img', 'image'); ?>
        <img src="<?= $servie->img; ?>">
        <?= $form->file('img', 'Choisissez une image'); ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
    </form>
```

my ServiceTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Table;

use Core\Table\Table;

class ServiceTable extends Table{

    protected $table = 'services';

    /**
     * Récupère les derniers article
     * @return array
     */
    public function last(){
        return $this->query("
            SELECT * FROM services");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think `$dir.$_FILES['img']['name']` should exist…?

Comment: Explain _WHY_ you are trying to delete anything here in the first place. (Because you don’t read the manual, presumably? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php: _“Warning: If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.”_)

Comment: @deceze '$file = $dir.$_FILES['img']['name'];
    if(file_exists($dir.$_FILES['img']['name'])) {
     echo "The file $file exists";
    }else{
     echo "The file doesn't $file exists";
    }'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the image already exists with that name, to then delete it before the upload, you could do:

```
if(file_exists($dir.$_FILES['img']['name'])) {
    unlink($dir.$_FILES['img']['name']);
}
```

To prevent any warnings being thrown.

Comment: thanks!  it's what i did before but but the old file till there !!!